# How to make a node js an exe file

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I make my Node JS application an executable file on Windows?

I've been trying to use the module [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) which works ok, but I am wanting to choose the icon myself! I tried to use multiple apps to change the icon, which did change the icon, but the app is not starting anymore and also if the app is executed as an administrator that it says company and my name are not unknown.

I packaged my file using: `pkg index.js`

If you could help me out it would be awesome!

It's not required to this to function on linux nor on other platforms, but only Windows.

Comment: so the question is making a nodejs file *WITH* custom icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the icons of executables generated with `pkg` with [ResourceHacker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Hacker). There is even a discussion about it on the [GitHub repository of `pkg`](https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/151).

In [this discussion](https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/91#issuecomment-365205915), a person even wrote a script to automate icon adding while building with `pkg`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) project